# How to store every second data in redis

Tags: redis

I am working on to find usage pattern. For every request I will take the corresponding second of the day and mark an entry. At the end I will see the usage pattern with this. What is the best structure to perform this in redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in three ways:

1) setbit operations storing in a single key

You can use setbit operations if the frequency is very high. That is if you mark for almost all the seconds then you have to store 86400 values inside that. But this will hardly take 0.1 Mb to store. 
Even if you store only one entry at 86400th second then you have to loose that 0.1 Mb. But it always have the fixed size as 0.1 Mb. Also beware that you can get the whole thing as a string and you have to convert them as bits.

```
setbit date second
get date
```

2) sets

You can use sets if the frequency is little low. So only those seconds in which the request comes will be in your set.

```
Sadd date second 
smembers date
```

3) hashes

You can use hashes if want to know the count for each second.

```
Hincrby date second 1
hgetall date
```

Also do a sample test with all these and compare the size and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I will go for 1st solution. Between how can I get all the bits values at once in redis. All I see is getbit command.

Comment: You have to get the result as a date and you have to convert them to corresponding bits in your app logic. The above link will help you to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hash to group by day.

```
// Set the counter to 0 if it doesn't exist.
HSETNX [DAY] [SECOND] 0

// Increment the counter by 1 each request
HINCRBY [DAY] [SECOND] 1
```

Then use `HKEYS` or `HSCAN` to get your results.

Comment: How can I do hsetnx if I don't have the request coming in at that second? Is that Hincrby alone is enough  for this operation?